# How do I request admin privileges for opening an .exe file?

Tags: batch-file, exe

I just made an `.exe` file with some quick batch file(`.bat`) commands...

And I was wondering:
how do I forcibly request elevated privileges on opening the `.exe` file? (without having to right click)

Comment: I improved some formatting and did some highlighting.

Comment: Wow. I think every virus need to have this code.

Answer (score 1):

For this one, you have to check if the batch file is elevated or not, then run a VBS file:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the file itself name
set filename=%0

rem Check if batch file is elevated or not:
reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19" >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo.Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "elevated.vbs"
  echo.UAC.ShellExecute "!filename!", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "elevated.vbs"
  "elevated.vbs"
  goto :eof
)
if %errorlevel%==0 goto elevated

:elevated
rem Now, run the exe file (like use 'start' command, or execute it as a command:
yourExecuteableFileInHere.exe
```

But the codes above still has some errors. You might want to fix it (or maybe not?)